# ObservableMap (mobx) returns undefined in views

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I have a component which renders table rows and some of the dates in columns is already cached as global data (loaded only at start), but I'm getting the following error: cannot read property 'name' of undefined at line 49 (check comments in given pieces of code).

The component (simplified):

```
const ApplicantRow = observer((props: ApplicantRowProps): React.ReactElement<any> => {
    const step = props.sandbox.globalData.cachedSteps.get(props.step.toString())
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="cols">
                // ... some cols
                <div className="col col-1of7">
                    <span>{`${props.step}. ${step.name}`}</span> // line 49, step is undefined but why?
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
})
```

and globalDate class:

```
class GlobalData implements jc.GlobalData {
    @observable public cachedSteps: ObservableMap<string, CachedStep> = observable.map()

    // This method is called when steps are fetched from a server and steps are passed as an argument
    public setCachedSteps(data: any): void {
        runInAction(() => {
            const steps = observable.map(data)
            this.cachedSteps = steps
        })
    }
}
```

I have tried to set a breakpoint at setCachedSteps method to ensure it's called before the ApplicantRow component, which means that there is data in globalDate.cachedSteps and it's weird why returning undefined?

Comment: In your component, you define 'step'. But you don't check to see if props.step exists - therefore toString() might fail, and the cacheSteps.get() call will fail, leaving 'step' as undefined. So your line 49 will fail because of that.

Comment: props.step exist, I have checked that!

Comment: As mentioned in above comment cachedSteps are set only after fetch, so until the first fetch completes the step will be `undefined`. However the react component can render before steps are fetched from server which leads to the error. Therefore it is always the good idea to check step for `undefined` before rendering.